# How do I backup 2 external hard disks to 1 external hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, backup

I currently own two 2 TB external hard disk and one 5 TB external hard disk. Is it possible to backup the two 2 TB external HDDs to the 5 TB external HDD using my Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can even be done in Time Machine:

Choose the 5 TB HDD as only Time Machine backup drive (OK, my disks are smaller  ):

[image: Choose backup drive]

Then exclude your internal drive by adding it to the excluded items - the backup drive is excluded automatically:

[image: exclude items Time Machine]

The final result:

You get a folder *Backups.backupdb* with one folder *vm* (the name of my Mac) containing folders (with date names representing the backup date) and each with two folders representing the two drives (*Data1* and *Encrypted*). I added and modified files successively on both volumes and initiated a backup after each step.

[image: final result]

---

**Needless to say: it's recommended to backup your main drive/system drive also!**

Comment: And Time Machine will backup both 2TB externals to the 5TB? How will the contents of each 2TB external be separated in the 5TB? Via 2 main folders?

Comment: @mannyrothman I will add screenshots soon!